# chrome driver version 122.0.6261.95

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

My chrome version is 122.0.6261.95.
But there is only 122.0.6261.94 on the chrome driver download web.
So I downloaded this and unzipped it to get chromedriver.exe and Lisence.chromedriver. I placed these two files in the Python file directory. however

raceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 90, in driver_location
output = self.run(args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 138, in run
raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.
{'code': 69, 'message': 'Driver unavailable: Driver path: ', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\�꒵����\��ũ�Ѹ�\insta\app.py", line 6, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

It pops up like this.

What is the problem? How do I solve it?

try to find some download chrome driver set on my chrome version, and find to solve the problem,...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem today as well. I found a solution in the link provided at the end of the error report, which can be found at https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager?tab=readme-ov-file#use-with-chrome.

Firstly, you need to install `pip install webdriver-manager`, and then you can use the following code snippet to create a Chrome browser driver if you are using selenium 4

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

I hope it can work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

- First, download the Chrome driver and unzip it
- create a path for your chrome driver like this

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  path = '/Users/sanjaymahto/Documents/mausham- kumar/chromedriver_mac64\chromdriver.exe'.   # path of your webdrive 
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```